# Remap to a subdir

Tags: .htaccess

I have an appplication which is ment to be outside public document root...but the hosting provider doesn't allow that...

How can I remap it?

structure:

```
/
/public_html/app
/public_html/new_public_html
```

"public_html" is the web server's document_root. "/" is the dir where I'd normally put my app (outside document_root". Since I'm not allowe to do this I neew to somehow remap it without breaking the other redirects...

So on access the server server files in "public_html" I need to redirect it to "new_public_html" where the public part od my app would be...

The "non public" part of my app would reside in "public_html".

The webserver needs to go directly to the `new_public_html` but there are other rules in effect:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Content routing
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for... in case anyone has a similar problem...

http://www.alberton.info/zend_framework_mod_rewrite_shared_hosting.html

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub_dir/$1 [L]
```

Sorry I didn't get it at once, I thought more complicated than it is.

Comment: I don't want to rewrite to non-public dirs... As I said there's a restriction which prevents me to put the app into non-public dirs... so they have to be in public dir... so i need to mirror that hierarchy...so that I don't have to rewrite my app...

Comment: Just to make this clear: RewriteRules allow you to access URLs that are public anyway _within_ the server. So what exactly do you want to achieve? http://server/index.html  -> http://server/sub_dir/index.html ? It would be really helpful if you'd give more information on your concrete problem, not just the symptom. Maybe there's an entirely other+better way.

Comment: server/index.html -> server/sub_dir/index.html - this is what I want to achieve. BTW this is somewhat I have posted in my question...

Comment: I'm sorry, I got confused by the part of public/non-public. Added the solution in an edit.